# Buscador tiempo real

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, codeigniter

Hola estoy realizando un buscador en tiempo real en codeigniter, jquery, json y mysql. entre el controlador y el modelo tengo comunicación, me trae los datos, pero en objeto.creo que el problema esta en enviar los datos al en array al js, alguna idea de como solucionarlo? tengo el siguiente código. 
esta es mi vista:

## BUSQUEDA

```
      <div class="formulario">
            <label for="caja_busqueda">Buscar</label>
              <input type="text" name="caja_busqueda" id="caja_busqueda"></input>
     </div>

      <div id="datos"></div>
```

mi controlador:

```
function listar()   {      $salida = "";

          if (isset($_POST['consulta'])) {
            $query = "SELECT id_persona, nombre_persona,apellido_persona, rut_persona, telefono_persona,
            nombre_comuna,edad_persona,nombre_carrera,nombre_ocupacion, fecha_persona FROM persona
            JOIN comuna on persona.id_comuna = comuna.id_comuna JOIN ocupacion on persona.id_ocupacion = ocupacion.id_ocupacion
            JOIN carrera ON persona.id_carrera = carrera.id_carrera WHERE nombre_persona LIKE '%$q%' OR apellido_persona LIKE '%$q%'
            OR rut_persona LIKE '%$q%' OR telefono_persona '%$q%' OR nombre_comuna '%$q%' OR edad_persona '%$q%' OR nombre_carrera '%$q%'
            OR nombre_ocupacion LIKE '%$q%' OR fecha_persona LIKE '$q' ";
          }
            $result = $this->Login_model->getdatos($query);
              echo json_encode($result);

              if ($result->num_rows>0) {
                $salida.="<table border=1 class='tabla_datos'>
                <thead>
                <tr id='titulo'>
                <td>ID</td> <td>NOMBRE</td> <td>APELLIDO</td> <td>RUT</td>
                <td>TELEFONO</td> <td>COMUNA</td> <td>EDAD</td>
                <td>CARRERA</td> <td>OCUPACION</td> <td>FECHA</td> </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>";

                while ($fila = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                  $salida.="<tr>
            <td>".$fila['id_persona']."</td>
            <td>".$fila['nombre_persona']."</td>
            <td>".$fila['apellido_persona']."</td>
            <td>".$fila['rut_persona']."</td>
            <td>".$fila['telefono_persona']."</td>
            <td>".$fila['nombre_comuna']."</td>
            <td>".$fila['edad_persona']."</td>
            <td>".$fila['nombre_carrera']."</td>
            <td>".$fila['nombre_ocupacion']."</td>
            <td>".$fila['fecha_persona']."</td>
            </tr>";
    }
      $salida.="</tbody></table>";
    }else{
      $salida.="NO HAY DATOS REGISTROS"; } echo $salida;}
```

el modelo:

```
function getdatos($consulta){
          $query=$this->db->query($consulta);
         return $query->result();
        }
```

mi js:

```
$(buscar_datos());

function buscar_datos(consulta){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/cft/index.php/lista_controller/listar' ,
        type: 'POST' ,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {consulta: consulta},
    })
    .done(function(respuesta){
        $("#datos").html(respuesta);
    })
    .fail(function(){
        console.log("error");
    });
}

$(document).on('keyup','#caja_busqueda', function(){
    var valor = $(this).val();
    if (valor != "") {
        buscar_datos(valor);
    }else{
        buscar_datos();
    }
});
```

Comment: Por favor [edit] la pregunta y agregue la descripción de los errores que tiene con este código.

Comment: lo siento, estoy recién ocupando esto amigo.